# Acceleration/velocity formulas for scrollers on iPhone/iPad?

Tags: jquery, ios, physics

I'm trying to emulate the scrolling list views in iOS, where you can scroll slowly, or flick with momentum and it scrolls till it decelerates and stops. I know there must be a way to mathematically program this behavior (something about measuring how many pixels were scrolled in the past X millseconds), but I suck at math. And yes, I realize there are a couple plug-ins for this, but I'd rather do this from scratch (for learning purposes).

Any advice would be great!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This looks like what you want:

http://www.developria.com/2010/09/elastic-scrolling-with-javascr.html

Comment: links go dead, you should put info in the post!  As it is this is useless.

Answer (score -1):

Have you checked what I've written about this topic in my blog: [flick list with its momentum scrolling and deceleration](http://ariya.ofilabs.com/2011/10/flick-list-with-its-momentum-scrolling-and-deceleration.html)?